# MySQL - group by UNIX_TIMESTAMP for dates before 1970

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a `GROUP BY` clause in my query:

```
SELECT * FROM currency_data
WHERE currency = 'GBP'
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) DIV (1440 * 60)
ORDER BY date ASC
```

This works fine for most records, however I have some records with a date < 1970. Therefore the group by ignores these records. Is there any way to make the group by work for these records?

My 'date' column is of type `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no UNIX TIMESTAMP before 1970 - that's timestamp 0.
You can group by the real date

In MySQL you can use this to get a negative number: `DATEDIFF( STR_TO_DATE('04-07-1968','%d-%m-%Y'),FROM_UNIXTIME(0))*24*36‌​00`

Comment: That may be true in MySQL, but then it is not really a Unix timestamp.  Negative values are allowed on Unix systems (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: In MySQL you can use this to get a negative number: DATEDIFF( STR_TO_DATE('04-07-1968','%d-%m-%Y'),FROM_UNIXTIME(0))*24*3600

Answer (score 3):

First, `select *` with `group by` is almost always the wrong thing to do.  You should be using aggregation functions.

There is no reason to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.  Just do

```
SELECT date(date), currency, min/max/avg/sum . . . 
FROM currency_data
WHERE currency = 'GBP'
GROUP BY date(date), currency
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: This returns a maximum of one record per date. I am using the `DIV` function to return data in intervals, so in some cases it needs to be in 15 minute intervals, as well as 24 hour intervals as is in my original post.